# C++ facade avoiding copies

Tags: c++, copy, facade

Consider the following, simplified facade pattern:

```
  class Foo {
  public:
    int times;

    int eval(const int val) { return val*times; }
  };

  class Bar {
    Foo foo;
  public:
    Bar(const Foo& f) : foo(f) {}

    double eval(const double val) { return val * foo.times; }
  };
```

Obviously, an instance of *Bar* is only required to evaluate a special (i.e. double-valued) interpretation of **Foo's eval()** method. A Bar won't have any other members except the *foo* it forwards to.

For safety reasons I have not used a `const` reference or a `pointer` inside Bar (I just don't know yet if at some point a Bar instance might escape from a `stack` frame, so resource management is important).

My question here is two fold:

1. Can the `C++` *compiler* possibly detect that Bar is merely a facade and
   "*inline*" the member access?
2. Is there a (safe) way to prevent copying
   of the passed object?

Comment: **1.** it probably will inline it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On some platforms (gcc/clang) you can force inlining with the attribute [always_inline](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) or emit warnings should a function not be inlined.
2. No, if you don't want to copy, you need to guarantee the life-time of the object elsewhere. If you consider this to be unsafe, don't do it. What you can do is move an object. This avoids copies and life-time issues, but might not be possible with your compiler.

For example:

```
 struct Bar {
   // Only accept rvalues of Foo
   explicit Bar(Foo&& f) : f(std::move(f)) {}
   Foo f;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes, the compiler will **most probably** inline the function [It depends on compiler).

2- Always stick to [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). In C++3, `Foo` object `foo` shall be either member variable (as you did), or managed pointer (copied at copy constructor and assignment operator and deleted at destructor). In C++11 you can use right value reference.

NOTE: This example is not a facade!

Comment: You are right, it also is an adapter, but I always considered a facade the more "general" description of that pattern (i.e. abstracting over the intention) - is this not the case?